# Add slice as row dynamically to 2d slice

Tags: go

I'm trying to add the slice `sofar` to a new row in `matrix` after each iteration.

```
func combinations(sofar []int, rest []int, n int, matrix [][]int, count int) {
    if n == 0 {
        //Next two lines problematic
        matrix[count] = append(matrix[count], sofar[0], sofar[1], sofar[2])
        count++
        fmt.Println(sofar)
        } else {
            for i := range rest[:len(rest)] {
                concat := sofar
                concat = append(concat, rest[i])
                combinations(concat, rest[i+1:], n-1, matrix, count)
            }
        }
}

func factorial(x uint) uint {
    if x == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return x * factorial(x-1)
}
```

Driver program

```
func triangleNumber() int {
    sofar := []int{}
    rest := []int{1,2,3,4}
    matrixSize := factorial(4)/(factorial(1)*factorial(3))
    matrix := make([][]int, matrixSize)
    count := 0 
    fmt.Println(matrixSize)
    combinations(sofar, rest, 3, matrix, count)
    return 0
}

triangleNumber()
```

I want `matrix` to be;

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 4]
[1 3 4]
[2 3 4]
```

But instead it's all going in the first row. Also is there a way I can get rid of `count`, and just add the slice `sofar` to the next row?

Comment: @ThunderCat done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are a couple of things I note with your program:

1. Append adds to the existing slice at its end (after length), so if you are using append for matrix, you need not allocate a slice of that size (see main in the code below)
2. After you are adding elements to the matrix, it is simply being dumped in your current program. The `combinations` function needs to return it back so that when future elements (slice of ints) are added, they are actually all there.

I've added some debugs and remodeled your program a bit, see if it makes sense:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    triangleNumber()
}
func combinations(sofar []int, rest []int, n int, matrix [][]int, count int) [][]int {
    fmt.Println("Entered with matrix", matrix)
    if n == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Entered with count", count)
        //Next two lines problematic
        matrix = append(matrix, sofar)
        count++
        fmt.Println(sofar)
        fmt.Println("Printing matrix\n***", matrix, "\n***")
        return matrix
    } else {
        for i := range rest[:len(rest)] {
            concat := sofar
            concat = append(concat, rest[i])
            matrix = combinations(concat, rest[i+1:], n-1, matrix, count)
            fmt.Println("Sending with count", count)
        }
    }
    return matrix
}

func factorial(x uint) uint {
    if x == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return x * factorial(x-1)
}

func triangleNumber() int {
    sofar := []int{}
    rest := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    matrixSize := factorial(4) / (factorial(1) * factorial(3))
    matrix := make([][]int, 0)
    count := 0
    fmt.Println(matrixSize)
    combinations(sofar, rest, 3, matrix, count)
    return 0
}
```

And as you can see, you can pretty much get rid of `count` too with this approach (look at the output). There's still some scope for improvement left though, but I guess this addresses what you were asking.

On playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rnCdPcaIG3N

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding all to the first row, and you need to add to the next row, see:
Try this (with minimum change to your code: made `count` a pointer):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    triangleNumber()
}
func triangleNumber() int {
    sofar := []int{}
    rest := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    matrixSize := factorial(4) / (factorial(1) * factorial(3))
    matrix := make([][]int, matrixSize)
    count := 0
    fmt.Println(matrixSize)
    combinations(sofar, rest, 3, matrix, &count)
    fmt.Println(matrix)

    return 0
}

func combinations(sofar []int, rest []int, n int, matrix [][]int, count *int) {
    if n == 0 {
        //Next two lines problematic
        matrix[*count] = append(matrix[*count], sofar[0], sofar[1], sofar[2])
        *count++
        //  fmt.Println(count, sofar)
    } else {
        for i := range rest[:len(rest)] {
            concat := sofar
            concat = append(concat, rest[i])
            combinations(concat, rest[i+1:], n-1, matrix, count)
        }
    }
}

func factorial(x uint) uint {
    if x == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return x * factorial(x-1)
}
```

output:

```
4
[[1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 3 4] [2 3 4]]
```

---

Also for your special case, this works too:

```
matrix[*count] = []int{sofar[0], sofar[1], sofar[2]}
```

instead of:

```
matrix[*count] = append(matrix[*count], sofar[0], sofar[1], sofar[2])
```